# PersistentVolume and PersistentVolumeClaim for multiple deployments

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I have 3 deployments, `a-depl`, `b-depl`, `c-depl`. Now each of these 3 deployments has a db deployment: `a-db-depl`, `b-db-depl`, `c-db-depl`.
Now I want to persist each of these dbs. Do I need to create a single PV for all or a PV for each of the deployments?

I know that PV <-> PVC is 1-to-1 relation. But I dont know about Depl <-> PV.
Can someone please help?

As of now, I have no clue, so I am using a single PV for all of the dp deployments

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mongo-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data/mongo"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mongo-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At a time one PV can be bound to only one PVC. So for each of your PVC you need to create a corresponding PV. To automate PV creation you can create a `StorageClass` and refer that `StorageClass` in your PVC. `StorageClass` can dynamically provision a PV for each PVC.

Whether multiple deployments can use the same PVC or PV depends on [`accessModes`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) of the PVC or PV.

`ReadOnlyMany` - the volume can be mounted read-only by many nodes

`ReadWriteMany`- the volume can be mounted as read-write by many nodes

`ReadWriteOnce` - the volume can be mounted as read-write by a single node

Answer (score 3):

How does one run multiple replicas of a pod and have each pod use its own storage
volume?
A **StatefulSet** resource, which is specifically tailored to applications where instances of the application must be treated as non-fungible individuals, with each one having a stable name and state.